# Caesar Shift in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, caesar-cipher

I started learning Haskell a couple of days ago and decided to build a Caesar shift in it.

```
import Data.Char

shift_str :: Int -> ([Char] -> [Char])
shift_str num
         | num > 1 = \str -> shift_str_forwards (shift_str (num-1) str)
         | num == 1 = shift_str_forwards
         | num == 0 = no_shift
         | num == -1 = shift_str_backwards
         | num < -1 = \str -> shift_str_backwards (shift_str (num+1) str)

no_shift :: [Char] -> [Char]
no_shift str = str

shift_str_forwards :: [Char] -> [Char]
shift_str_forwards str = map shift_forwards str

shift_str_backwards :: [Char] -> [Char]
shift_str_backwards str = map shift_backwards str

shift_forwards :: Char -> Char
shift_forwards char
             | char == 'z' = 'a'
             | otherwise = chr (1 + ord char)

shift_backwards :: Char -> Char
shift_backwards char
              | char == 'a' = 'z'
              | otherwise = chr (ord char - 1)
```

However, this seems far too complex to be the right way of doing it. Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, it's great that you use type signatures. However, your using `snake_case`, whereas Haskell usually uses `camelCase` for functions, e.g. `no_shift` should be called `noShift`.

Next, your shift functions for characters can be simplified by both pattern matching and `succ` and `pred`:

```
shiftForwards :: Char -> Char
shiftForwards 'z' = 'a'
shiftForwards c   = succ c

shiftBackwards :: Char -> Char
shiftBackwards 'a' = 'z'
shiftBackwards c   = pred c
```

Next, your "global" function gets easier if you use `str` as an argument and not in a lambda.

```
shiftStr :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
shiftStr num str
       | num > 0  = shiftStr (num - 1) (map shiftForwards str)
       | num < 0  = shiftStr (num + 1) (map shiftBackwards str)
       | num == 0 = str
```

The special cases for `num == 1` and `num == -1` aren't necessary, since `shiftStr` will return immediately if the subsequent call uses `num = 0`.

Answer (score 6):

`shiftStr` 'encrypts' each letter of input string independently of other letters. This could be emphasized by using `map` at the top of `shiftStr` instead of hiding it in helper functions:

```
shiftStr :: Int -> String -> String
shiftStr n xs = map (shiftChar n) xs
```

Or in [pointfree style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) without variables:

```
shiftStr :: Int -> String -> String
shiftStr = map . shiftChar
```

`shiftChar n c` replaces letter by searching for another one `n` positions away. I'll implement this literally by creating cycled alphabet and searching for letters in it. This is inefficient but allows to get taste of laziness.

```
alphabet = ['a'..'z'] :: String
alphaLoop = cycle alphabet :: String

shiftChar :: Int -> Char -> Char
shiftChar n c = head $ drop n $ dropWhile (/= c) alphaLoop
```

[`cycle`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:cycle) creates cycle from a list. [`dropWhile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:dropWhile) skips some characters and returns list starting from `c`.

Try it in ghci (`alphaLoop` is infinite so be careful with it).

```
> let alphaLoop = cycle ['a'..'z']
> take 30 alphaLoop
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd"
> take 30 $ dropWhile (/= 'x') alphaLoop
"xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza"
> take 30 $ drop 1 $ dropWhile (/= 'x') alphaLoop
"yzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab"
```

`alphaLoop` is a loop, so we can skip `length alphabet - 10` letters instead of moving 10 letters backwards:

```
shiftChar :: Int -> Char -> Char
shiftChar n c = head $ drop (length alpha + n) $ dropWhile (/= c) alphaLoop
```

Full code is like this:

```
shiftStr :: Int -> String -> String
shiftStr n = map shiftChar
  where
    alphabet = ['a'..'z']
    alphaLoop = cycle alphabet
    shiftChar c = head
        $ drop (length alphabet + n)
        $ dropWhile (/= c) alphaLoop
```

Now try `shiftStr 13 "ABC"` and see if you can explain its behavior.